# Filtering with DjangoFilterBackend does not found the url

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, http-status-code-404

I'm using Django rest framework 3.8.2.

I have read [api-guide/filtering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/) and followed the given example for the `DjangoFilterBackend` section.

**models.py**

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=False)
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Pregunta_Categoria, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    tipoRespuesta = models.ForeignKey(TipoRespuesta, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='fk_id_tipoRespuesta') #sacar el default
    privated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='A')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='proy_created_by8')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='proy_modified_by8')
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_pregunta', 'View Pregunta'),
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

**views.py**

```
class PreguntaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pregunta.objects.filter(estado='A')
    serializer_class = PreguntaSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('name', 'privated')
```

Here is my serializer:

```
class PreguntaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nom_tipoRespuesta = serializers.CharField(
        source="tipoRespuesta.nombre", required=False, allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        fields = (
            'id', 'name', 'descripcion', 'categoria', 'tipoRespuesta',
            'created_by', 'created_on', 'modified_by', 'modified_on',
            'status', 'privated', 'nom_tipoRespuesta',
        )
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from proy import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'questions', views.PreguntaViewSet)
router.register(r'questionCategories', views.PreguntaCategoriaViewSet)
router.register(r'projects', views.ProyectoViewSet)
router.register(r'polls', views.EncuestaViewSet)
router.register(r'questionnaire', views.CuestionarioViewSet)
router.register(r'pollByUser', views.EncuestaPorUsuarioViewSet)
router.register(r'answerType', views.TipoRespuestaViewSet)
router.register(r'answers', views.RespuestaViewSet)
router.register(r'answerByUser', views.RespuestaPorUsuarioViewSet)
router.register(r'variablesType', views.TipoVariableViewSet)
router.register(r'variablesCategory', views.CategoriaVariableViewSet)
router.register(r'variables', views.VariableViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'adm.exceptions.core_exception_handler',
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'error',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
}
```

However, when I try the url

```
http://example.com/api/questions?name=someName&privated=True
```

I get the error `Page not found (404)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the URL should be `example.com/` ? Do you have your code in that URL or have you set it up in your local `hosts` file? If not, you should check where your Django server is listening (probably `127.0.0.1:8000`).

Comment: `example.com/api/questions?name=someName&privated=True` was only a example, the real url is `localhost:8000/api/v1/questions?name=someName&privated=True`  @Ralf

Comment: Do other URLs work? For example `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/questionCategories/` or `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/pools/`? Are you including the correct version (`v1/`) in the path?

Comment: @Ralf Yes, others URLs works

Answer (score 0):

By default the URLs created by [DefaultRouter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter) are appended with a trailing slash, try this url:

```
http://example.com/api/questions/?name=someName&privated=True
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not retrieve any data, it shows me a django rest framework window used to post, get data

Comment: @AngelPineda looks like you dont have records with name=someName&privated=True values. Not sure but I suppose True should be lowercased. Try `name=someName&privated=true`.

Comment: @nerverwalkaloner `name=someName&privated=True` is just a example, I have many records